# Enable button in rows with inputs

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have table with rows with 2 inputs and button, I want to enable the button when the two inputs are enabled,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(this).find('.save-btn').prop('disabled', true);
  $('.input').keyup(function() {
    $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var value = $row.find('input[name="value"]').val();
    var date = $row.find('input[name="name"]').val();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.save-btn').prop('disabled', !(value && date));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="input" name="date"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input" name="name"></td>
        <td><button class="btn save-btn">Save</button></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="input" name="date"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input" name="name"></td>
        <td><button class="btn save-btn">Save</button></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="input" name="date"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input" name="name"></td>
        <td><button class="btn save-btn">Save</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am saving the inputs using ajax and find method but I can't use it to enable and disabled the button, any help?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be targeting the wrong name.  You target inputs where name is `value` instead of `date`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).find('.save-btn').prop('disabled', true);
  
  $('.input').keyup(function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        value = $row.find('input[name="date"]').val(),
        date = $row.find('input[name="name"]').val();
    $row.find('.save-btn').prop('disabled', !(value && date));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="input" name="date"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input" name="name"></td>
        <td><button class="btn save-btn">Save</button></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="input" name="date"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input" name="name"></td>
        <td><button class="btn save-btn">Save</button></td>
    </tr> 

    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="input" name="date"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input" name="name"></td>
        <td><button class="btn save-btn">Save</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it was a typo, still the same problem :(

Comment: @Peril My version works though, so there must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

When the inputs are enabled, that means you could enter any thing into them. At the same time, you would have an implementation on keydown, keyup, or keychange to enable buttons.